# sp_send_dbmail scheduled job execute only IF results <> 0

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, scheduled-tasks, sp-send-dbmail

I have the follow scheduled job -

```
Execute as login = 'sa'
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
@profile_name = 'SQL Mail Profile',
@recipients = 'Tania.Mofflin@fuelfix.com.au',
@subject = 'Wennsoft Service Management - Unposted Costs',
@body = 'Unposted Costs from Closed POs:
        ',
@execute_query_database = 'FPLL',
@query = 'Select A.Service_Call_ID as "Service Call", A.Reference_TRX_Number as "Reference Number", A.WS_Committed_Cost as "Committed Cost"
            from SV000810 A LEFT JOIN POP10110 B on A.Reference_TRX_Number = B.PONUMBER and A.SEQNUMBR = B.ORD
            where A.WS_Committed_Cost <> 0 and B.QTYUNCMTBASE = 0'
```

Which works fine but I would like to include an IF statement where it only executes if there are no results.

Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but...
Since the job step you are working with is simply T-SQL, you could do something like this:

```
IF exists(Select *
        from SV000810 A LEFT JOIN POP10110 B on A.Reference_TRX_Number = B.PONUMBER and 
        A.SEQNUMBR = B.ORD where A.WS_Committed_Cost <> 0 and B.QTYUNCMTBASE = 0)
BEGIN
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
@profile_name = 'SQL Mail Profile',
@recipients = 'Tania.Mofflin@fuelfix.com.au',
@subject = 'Wennsoft Service Management - Unposted Costs',
@body = 'Unposted Costs from Closed POs:
        ',
@execute_query_database = 'FPLL',
@query = 'Select A.Service_Call_ID as "Service Call", A.Reference_TRX_Number as 
    "Reference Number", A.WS_Committed_Cost as "Committed Cost"
        from SV000810 A LEFT JOIN POP10110 B on A.Reference_TRX_Number = B.PONUMBER and 
        A.SEQNUMBR = B.ORD
        where A.WS_Committed_Cost <> 0 and B.QTYUNCMTBASE = 0'
END
```

Note how the query is being run twice here, so it's not the best performing.  You could dump the query results in a temp table and then do the EXISTS() and email using the temp table, or you could use a table variable if you prefer.  The above is only the quickest path to what you were trying for.